# Cannot update an instance due to a PATCH routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update an instance of a game but I'm receiving a routing error even though I'm providing all resources to games.

```
Started PATCH "/games" for ::1 at 2020-01-16 20:18:21 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/games"):
```

This is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :games
end
```

And this is my update method in the Game controller

```
  def update
    game = Game.find_by(id: params[:id])

    if game.update(game_params)
      render json: { message: "Accepted initials." }
    else
      render json: { message: "Didn't accept initials" },
      status: :not_acceptable
    end
  end

  private

  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(
      :score,
      :initials,
      :total_calories
    )
  end
```

If it helps, this is my fetch PATCH request

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/games", {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        game: {
          score: this.props.state.currentGame.score,
          initials: this.state.initials,
          total_calories: this.props.state.currentGame.total_calories
        }
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your patch route is 'http://localhost:3000/games/:id', and not 'http://localhost:3000/games'.
So it should be...

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/games/" + "<find a way to get game id>", {
```